# Parse Objective - C to Swift iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am having trouble trying to change Objective - C code to Swift. This is with the Parse framework. If anyone knows how the following code should be written in Swift, it would help me a lot.

```
 [user signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        //The registration was successful, go to the wall
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SignupSuccesful" sender:self];

    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[NSObject: Anyobject]? does not have a member named subscript parse compile error will be thrown.

The code should be like that because userInfor maybe be nil.

```
user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (succeeded: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    if !(error != nil) {
        // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
    } else {
        if let errorString = error.userInfo?["error"] as? NSString {
            println(errorString)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can even improve your solution casting like that: if let errorString = error.userInfo?["error"] as? String {

Answer (score 1):

Parse happens to have [an example of this exact method](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#top/iOS) in their documentation. I think they'll be OK if I excerpt it here:

```
user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
  (succeeded: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
  if !error {
    // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
  } else {
    let errorString = error.userInfo["error"] as NSString
    // Show the errorString somewhere and let the user try again.
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work using Xcode 6.1 and iOS 8.1. See rather the Meshari Alsuhaibani's solution below.

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like this.

```
user.signUpInBackground {
    (success: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    if !error {
        [unowned self] in
        self.performSegue("SignupSuccesful", sender:self);
}
```

Edit: Parse actually has Swift support. [Here's a tutorial](http://blog.parse.com/2014/06/06/building-apps-with-parse-and-swift/) for it.

Edit2: You shouldn't refer to self inside a block. Use `unowned self` instead.

Comment: You can bridge their current Objective - C framework to Swift. So their framework works with Swift.

Comment: This isn't valid Swift. Type annotations go after variable names, and you don't signify pointers with `*`.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the user's code and forgot to edit that part.